# crop image with imagemagick Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, imagemagick, crop

It's the first time that im using imagemagick 
well im trying to crop an image but the problem is that i get this error :

> Image processing failed. Please verify that your server supports the
>   chosen protocol and that the path to your image library is correct.

here is my code

```
$config['image_library'] = 'imagemagick';
$config['library_path'] = '/usr/bin';
$config['source_image'] ="./assets/profile_pic.jpg";
$config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
$config['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
$config['x_axis'] = 300;
$config['y_axis'] = 300;
//$config['width'] = 650;
//$config['height'] = 353;      
$config['new_image'] = "./assets/profile_pic.jpg";

$this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
//$this->image_lib->crop();
$this->image_lib->initialize($config); 
if (!$this->image_lib->crop()){
    echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
}
```

So should i download imagemagick or something like that ?

thx guys !

Comment: why not using GD2 ? :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below has given me expected result. Hope you will also get same.

```
    $this->load->library('image_lib');

    //For resizing of image in size of dilog
    $config['image_library']  = 'ImageMagick';
    $config['library_path'] = 'C:\\ImageMagick\\';

    $config['source_image'] = $source_filepath;
    $config['new_image'] = $new_filepath;

    $config['quality'] = '100%';
    $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
    $config['x_axis'] = 26;
    $config['y_axis'] = 54;
    $config['width'] = 100;
    $config['height'] = 100;

    $this->image_lib->initialize($config);

    if (!$this->image_lib->crop()){
        $error_msg = $this->image_lib->display_errors();
        print_r($error_msg);
    }
    else {
        echo "Done";
    }
```

Here

```
$config['library_path'] = 'C:\\ImageMagick\\';
```

is the path for windows where your imageMagick application is installed.(Try to install in such a folder to which we can easily map it for library path).
Change the image library to :

```
$config['image_library']  = 'ImageMagick';
```

& other all configuration is remains same.

Comment: so I can install it in project folders? but what happens when I will upload it to the server?